# DataGridView is hidden behind MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, menustrip

I'm displaying a `DataGridView` object in the application, but a part of it is hidden behind a `MenuStrip` (in the same application) which is at the top of the screen.

I don't know if that matters but the `MenuStrip` is created with the Visual Studio designer, while the `DataGridVie`w is created programmatically.

I set the `DataGridView`'s object to `DockStyle.Fill`, I have tried other styles and I have also tried to use`AnchorStyle`, neither worked.

The part that is hidden is pretty much the column headers part.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe set it somehow relative to the `MenuStrip`?

Comment: Right mouse click on the DataGridView control and select BringToFront.

Comment: The DataGridView is created programmatically.. offcourse you could call myGrid.BringToFront() from code, but this won't solve the issue..

Comment: @TDull Why won't calling BringToFront work?  I'm pretty sure it will.

Comment: @LarsTech I belive that the MenuStrip will always stay on top.. however if I'm wrong he would end up hiding his MenuStrip behind the grid

Comment: @LarsTech As TDull said, the DataGridView is created programmatically so I have no option to do that.

Comment: @user3705007 Good stuff ! Me (and my enormous amount of rep) would appreciate it if you accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the Anchor property instead of the dock property. Something like this should work:

```
grid.Top = menuStrip1.Height;
grid.Height = this.ClientSize.Height - menuStrip1.Height; //this => parent form
grid.Width = this.ClientSize.Width;
grid.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

EDIT: Note that
if the DockProperty is set to anything else than **None** this will override the Anchor property

Edit: Updated Typing Mistake

Answer (score 1):

The order of controls getting added to the form are affecting the layout when you use a property like Dock.  You can simple use the BringToFront method to fix the issue:

```
MenuStrip ms = new MenuStrip();
ms.Items.Add("File");
this.Controls.Add(ms);

DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Columns.Add("Test", "Test");
dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(dgv);
dgv.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Thank you, using BringToFront method solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First check the current Parent by putting this in the Form's Load or Shown event:

```
Console.WriteLine( menuStrip1.Parent.Text + "<---menuStrip1.Parent---");
```

If the `MenuStrip` is correctly docked you should see your Form's title text in the output..
If it isn't you can log out the `menuStrip1.Parent.Name`. And maybe it is enough to set the parent to be the form before docking the `DataGridView`:

```
menuStrip1.Parent = this;
```

But **if** that helps you really ought to fix the initial error:

Remove the `MenuStrip` (cut), make sure there is free room for it at the top of the `Form` and add it again (paste). If they don't have proper space to dock to the top of the window `MenuStrips` tend to dock somewhere else and then mess up the layout.